# What is the best way to cast variables when unpacking iterables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code I am reading lines from a file. Each line contains space delimited values.

```
foo True 8 9.2
bar False 17 -3.1
```

After reading the file and splitting the text by line. I will end up with a list.

```
lines = ['foo True 8 9.2', 'bar False 17 -3.1']
```

I then iterate through the lines and unpack the variables using `.split()`:

```
for line in lines:
    string, boolean, integer, floating_point = line.split()
```

I then cast each variable to its proper type:

```
boolean = bool(boolean)
integer = int(integer)
floating_point = float(floating_point)
```

My question is, is there a more Pythonic way to cast the variables and/or use less lines?

Comment: Well, you could always write `string, boolean, integer, floating_point = [typ(val) for typ, val in zip([str, bool, int, float], line.split())]`.  Or you could stick with what you've got, which is *actually readable*.

Comment: Iterate over your file directly: `for line in fh: line = line.split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast


def convert(s):
    """ Determine value of (Python) literal given in string `s`. """
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s


filename = 'data_file.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        string, boolean, integer, floating_point = (convert(item) for item in line.split())
        print(string, boolean, integer, floating_point)
```

Output:

```
foo True 8 9.2
bar False 17 -3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval`. Unlike `eval` this only determines literals.

```py
from ast import literal_eval


lines = ['foo True 8 9.2', 'bar False 17 -3.1']

for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        try:
            eval_ed = literal_eval(word)
        except ValueError:
            eval_ed = word  # it's a string, EAFP at it's finest
        print(type(eval_ed), eval_ed)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> foo
<class 'bool'> True
<class 'int'> 8
<class 'float'> 9.2
<class 'str'> bar
<class 'bool'> False
<class 'int'> 17
<class 'float'> -3.1
```

Comment: Well, not for ```str```. ```literal_eval``` will raise ```ValueError``` for string. I don't think we need separate function with ```try-except``` just to use it for ```map```.

Answer (score 0):

when logic gets messy usually the solution is to abstract that logic to another function, and if the function represents an iterable then you would write a generator, for instance you could do this:

```
def mapTypes(values, types):
    return (cast(v) for cast, v in zip(types, values))

def mapRows(file, rowTypes):
    for line in file:
        yield mapTypes(line.split(), rowTypes)


def str2bool(string):
    if string == "True":
        return True
    elif string == "False":
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError("string must be True or False, got {!r}".format(string))


lines = ['foo True 8 9.2', 'bar False 17 -3.1']
for row in mapRows(lines, [str, str2bool, int,float]):
    string, boolean, integer, floating_point = row
    print(string, boolean, integer, floating_point)
```